# ANR executing service com.onesignal.SyncService

Tags: android, onesignal

We are using OneSignal Native SDK version 3.4 in my app and sometime crash the app give below crash log :

```
"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 Runnable
| group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c060d0 self=0x7b16ad0400
| sysTid=29468 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b15487450
| state=R schedstat=( 38449486 526559 113 ) utm=0 stm=2 core=1 HZ=100
| stack=0x7b1538d000-0x7b1538f000 stackSize=1005KB
| held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 TimedWaiting
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x76dc28d0 self=0x7b16aa1a00
| sysTid=29462 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b1ab15a98
| state=S schedstat=( 342720854 559444785 1097 ) utm=18 stm=15 core=2 HZ=100
| stack=0x7fec5e8000-0x7fec5ea000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes=
at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)


waiting on <0x06dd0cbb> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:407)
at java.lang.Thread.join (Thread.java:1313)
locked <0x06dd0cbb> (a java.lang.Object)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.putSync (OneSignalRestClient.java)
at <OR>.makeRequest (OneSignalRestClient.java)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.putSync (OneSignalRestClient.java)
at <OR>.makeRequest (OneSignalRestClient.java)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalStateSynchronizer.handleJsonArray (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at <OR>.stopAndPersist (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at <OR>.initUserState (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at <OR>.syncUserState (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at <OR>.postUpdate (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at <OR>.sendTags (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at <OR>.updateLocation (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at <OR>.access$300 (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at <OR>.access$600 (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at <OR>.access$900 (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at <OR>.access$1100 (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java)
at com.onesignal.SyncService$2$1.complete (SyncService.java)
at com.onesignal.LocationGMS.scheduleUpdate (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.setLastLocationTime (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.getLocation (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.startGetLocation (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.fireComplete (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.access$200 (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.access$302 (LocationGMS.java)
locked <0x09a195d8> (a java.lang.Class<com.onesignal.u>)
at com.onesignal.LocationGMS.getLastLocationTime (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.fireFailedComplete (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.receivedLocationPoint (LocationGMS.java)
at com.onesignal.LocationGMS.scheduleUpdate (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.setLastLocationTime (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.getLocation (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.startGetLocation (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.fireComplete (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.access$200 (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.access$302 (LocationGMS.java)
at com.onesignal.LocationGMS$GoogleApiClientListener.onConnected (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.onConnectionSuspended (LocationGMS.java)
at <OR>.onConnectionFailed (LocationGMS.java)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl.zzass (zzl.java)
at <OR>.zzo (zzl.java)
at <OR>.zzgb (zzl.java)
at <OR>.zzm (zzl.java)
at <OR>.registerConnectionCallbacks (zzl.java)
at <OR>.registerConnectionFailedListener (zzl.java)
locked <0x0284cd31> (a java.lang.Object)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqd.zzc (zzqd.java)
at <OR>.zza (zzqd.java)
at <OR>.connect (zzqd.java)
at <OR>.registerConnectionFailedListener (zzqd.java)
```

We can not reproduce the problem. If you need anything else for further investigating the problem I am here to help.

Comment: Post the full dump-  this is a partial one.

Comment: Given above is full dump @Gabe

Comment: Below link is full dump : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276221/application-not-responding-anr-executing-service-com-onesignal-syncservice

Answer (score 0):

The [OneSignal Android SDK 3.5.7](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases/tag/3.5.7) fixes a bug where an ANR sometimes occurs during intermittent network connections. The linked issue notes that same stack trace so this update should fix your issue.