# Application Not Responding (ANR) Executing service com.onesignal.SyncService

Tags: android, onesignal

We are using OneSignal Native SDK version 3.+ in my app and sometime crash the app.

Give below onesignal dependencies :

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
```

Onesignal init method :

```
OneSignal.startInit(this).
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new MyNotificationOpenedHandler())
            .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new MyNotificationReceivedHandler())
            .init();
```

Crash log :

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41acb578 self=0x419cf6a8
| sysTid=25516 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074106364
| state=S schedstat=( 176067213 49796364 292 ) utm=13 stm=4 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42702938> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=21 (OS_HTTPConnection)
at java.lang.Thread.join (Thread.java:809)
at java.lang.Thread.join (Thread.java:765)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.makeRequest (OneSignalRestClient.java:102)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.putSync (OneSignalRestClient.java:82)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalStateSynchronizer.syncUserState (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java:586)
at com.onesignal.SyncService$2$1.complete (SyncService.java:91)
at com.onesignal.LocationGMS.fireComplete (LocationGMS.java:208)
at com.onesignal.LocationGMS.receivedLocationPoint (LocationGMS.java:233)
at com.onesignal.LocationGMS.access$200 (LocationGMS.java:54)
at com.onesignal.LocationGMS$GoogleApiClientListener.onConnected (LocationGMS.java:247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1046)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:862)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)

"OS_HTTPConnection" prio=5 tid=22 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4270ce68 self=0x41a84870
| sysTid=25597 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1101548736
| state=S schedstat=( 13628457 6080085 21 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=1
native: pc 000000000001b68c  /system/lib/libc.so (select+20)
native: pc 0000000000026ccd  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
native: pc 000000000002929d  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
native: pc 000000000001e44c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
native: pc 000000000004e91b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
native: pc 0000000000027860  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000002be00  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
native: pc 0000000000060a6d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)
native: pc 0000000000060a97  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
native: pc 000000000005582b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000000cb58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
native: pc 000000000000ccd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake (Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:398)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket (HttpConnection.java:209)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest (HttpEngine.java:290)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest (HttpEngine.java:240)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.startHTTPConnection (OneSignalRestClient.java:142)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.access$100 (OneSignalRestClient.java:38)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient$4.run (OneSignalRestClient.java:94)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"OS_HTTPConnection" prio=5 tid=21 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42702538 self=0x4006a3e8
| sysTid=25548 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074178104
| state=S schedstat=( 14957377 5977415 32 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
native: pc 000000000001b68c  /system/lib/libc.so (select+20)
native: pc 0000000000026ccd  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
native: pc 000000000002929d  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
native: pc 000000000001e44c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
native: pc 000000000004e91b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
native: pc 0000000000027860  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000002be00  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
native: pc 0000000000060a6d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)
native: pc 0000000000060a97  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
native: pc 000000000005582b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000000cb58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
native: pc 000000000000ccd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
at       org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake (Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:398)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket (HttpConnection.java:209)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest (HttpEngine.java:290)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest (HttpEngine.java:240)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.startHTTPConnection (OneSignalRestClient.java:142)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.access$100 (OneSignalRestClient.java:38)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient$4.run (OneSignalRestClient.java:94)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"GAC_Executor[1]" prio=5 tid=18 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426f0e80 self=0x59415ac0
| sysTid=25547 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1496677472
| state=S schedstat=( 3326415 1574126 8 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x426f1020> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=18 (GAC_Executor[1])
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"GAC_Executor[0]" prio=5 tid=20 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426e4f08 self=0x59415010
| sysTid=25546 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1497453664
| state=S schedstat=( 13563253 10066624 18 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x426e5140> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=20 (GAC_Executor[0])
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"OS_GMS_LOCATION_FALLBACK" prio=5 tid=19 MONITOR
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426d4ae8 self=0x59356630
| sysTid=25545 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1496672896
| state=S schedstat=( 40754088 80571253 418 ) utm=0 stm=4 core=0
at com.onesignal.LocationGMS.fireFailedComplete (LocationGMS.java:202)
at com.onesignal.LocationGMS$1.run (LocationGMS.java:192)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"OSH_NetworkHandlerThread" prio=5 tid=17 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426d2850 self=0x59357010
| sysTid=25543 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1496675424
| state=S schedstat=( 22462710 4191081 20 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4270cf20> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=22 (OS_HTTPConnection)
at java.lang.Thread.join (Thread.java:809)
at java.lang.Thread.join (Thread.java:765)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.makeRequest (OneSignalRestClient.java:102)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.putSync (OneSignalRestClient.java:82)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalStateSynchronizer.syncUserState (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java:586)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalStateSynchronizer$NetworkHandlerThread$1.run (OneSignalStateSynchronizer.java:527)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:176)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)

"FocusHandlerThread" prio=5 tid=16 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426cafb0 self=0x40026828
| sysTid=25542 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073902320
| state=S schedstat=( 421167 0 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
native: pc 000000000001c664  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
native: pc 00000000000153f1  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+92)
native: pc 0000000000015615  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
native: pc 0000000000072235  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
native: pc 000000000001e44c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
native: pc 000000000004e91b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
native: pc 0000000000027860  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000002be00  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
native: pc 0000000000060a6d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)
native: pc 0000000000060a97  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
native: pc 000000000005582b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000000cb58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
native: pc 000000000000ccd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:132)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:138)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)

"pool-2-thread-1" prio=5 tid=15 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42696f58 self=0x40013e30
| sysTid=25538 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073824384
| state=S schedstat=( 3977335 1149084 11 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42698470> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=15 (pool-2-thread-1)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1052)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:780)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=11 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42691970 self=0x4000c4f8
| sysTid=25537 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073826976
| state=S schedstat=( 1992832 0 7 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42691ab8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=11 (pool-1-thread-1)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos (LockSupport.java:199)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2058)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1063)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:780)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4267b688 self=0x400132d8
| sysTid=25535 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073821480
| state=S schedstat=( 10104750 21937459 43 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4267b7c8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=14 (AsyncTask #4)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=13 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4267a7c8 self=0x400129b0
| sysTid=25534 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073819136
| state=S schedstat=( 587500 42750 3 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4267a968> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=13 (AsyncTask #3)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42675408 self=0x40012008
| sysTid=25533 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073816664
| state=S schedstat=( 7128207 5538125 30 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42675528> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=12 (AsyncTask #2)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426677a0 self=0x4000bbb0
| sysTid=25531 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073790976
| state=S schedstat=( 30066581 26143916 61 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=0
native: pc 000000000001b68c  /system/lib/libc.so (select+20)
native: pc 0000000000026ccd  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
native: pc 000000000002929d  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
native: pc 000000000001e44c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
native: pc 000000000004e91b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
native: pc 0000000000027860  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000002be00  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
native: pc 0000000000060a6d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)
native: pc 0000000000060a97  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
native: pc 000000000005582b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000000cb58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
native: pc 000000000000ccd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake (Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:398)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket (HttpConnection.java:209)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest (HttpEngine.java:290)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest (HttpEngine.java:240)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
at com.facebook.GraphResponse.fromHttpConnection (GraphResponse.java:253)
at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeConnectionAndWait (GraphRequest.java:1270)
at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait (GraphRequest.java:1168)
at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait (GraphRequest.java:1134)
at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait (GraphRequest.java:1118)
at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait (GraphRequest.java:1093)
at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait (GraphRequest.java:987)
at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.getAppSettingsQueryResponse (FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:207)
at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.access$100 (FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:47)
at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager$1.run (FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4263be10 self=0x418ef250
| sysTid=25528 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1099886600
| state=S schedstat=( 3381083 644501 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
native: pc 000000000001b53c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
native: pc 000000000002bccf  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
native: pc 000000000001b929  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
native: pc 000000000001c0c7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
native: pc 00000000000200d1  /system/lib/libbinder.so
native: pc 0000000000011d7d  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
native: pc 0000000000054a3d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
native: pc 0000000000011871  /system/lib/libutils.so
native: pc 000000000000cb58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
native: pc 000000000000ccd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (Native Method)

"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4263bcb0 self=0x5942a850
| sysTid=25527 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1497540104
| state=S schedstat=( 2974501 4290374 7 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
native: pc 000000000001b53c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
native: pc 000000000002bccf  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
native: pc 000000000001b929  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
native: pc 000000000001c0c7  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
native: pc 00000000000200d1  /system/lib/libbinder.so
native: pc 0000000000011d7d  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
native: pc 0000000000054a3d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
native: pc 0000000000011871  /system/lib/libutils.so
native: pc 000000000000cb58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
native: pc 000000000000ccd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42637b48 self=0x59429d68
| sysTid=25525 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1497539000
| state=S schedstat=( 76208 0 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41ad3908> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:364)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject (Daemons.java:230)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run (Daemons.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426379f0 self=0x59429710
| sysTid=25524 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073797808
| state=S schedstat=( 76750 0 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41abc568> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:401)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:102)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:73)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run (Daemons.java:170)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42637888 self=0x4000d210
| sysTid=25523 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073796704
| state=S schedstat=( 145375 0 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41abc490>
at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:364)
at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run (Daemons.java:130)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42637798 self=0x40177458
| sysTid=25522 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075278352
| state=S schedstat=( 57876996 11472874 88 ) utm=2 stm=3 core=1
native: pc 000000000001c82c  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
native: pc 000000000000e7bc  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
native: pc 000000000000e81c  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
native: pc 0000000000073eb5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 0000000000054f0d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000000cb58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
native: pc 000000000000ccd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
| group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x426376a0 self=0x59425d60
| sysTid=25521 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1497535320
| state=R schedstat=( 50525832 24623126 89 ) utm=2 stm=3 core=0
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426375c0 self=0x5976db30
| sysTid=25520 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1497534480
| state=S schedstat=( 574333 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
native: pc 000000000001c82c  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
native: pc 000000000000e7bc  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
native: pc 000000000000e81c  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
native: pc 00000000000729ab  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 0000000000054f0d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000000cb58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
native: pc 000000000000ccd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run (Native Method)
```

We can not reproduce the problem. If you need anything else for further investigating the problem I am here to help.

Comment: Yes this kind of issues i am also facing, any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OneSignal Android SDK 3.5.7 fixes a bug where an ANR sometimes occurs during intermittent network connections. The linked issue notes that same stack trace so this update should fix your issue.

Comment: @Amjad Khan Check your OneSignal Android SDK version and set this

Answer (score 0):

@Dixit Patel Application Not Responding (ANR) error happens when app performs a potentially lengthy operation and blocks the UI thread.
To resolve your issue you can either increase the efficiency of your code or create a worker thread and do the sync part there.